# Change the color of an element when another element is selected in the ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Tell. When I select an item in the list, the item's color changes to green, so I can select all items - all items change color to green. But I need that when another element is selected, the previous element returns to its previous state. That is, so that only one element can burn green, and not all. Tell me how to implement? I will be grateful.

**code**

```
class _ListPoynts extends State<ListPoynts> {

  final List<bool> _selected = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (var i = 0; i < poynts.length; i++) {
      _selected.add(false);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

ListView.builder(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: poynts.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              child: Container(
                width: 176,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _selected[index] = !_selected.elementAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 72,
                    width: 146,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      color: _selected[index]
                          ? constants.Colors.greenMiddle
                          : constants.Colors.greyDark.withOpacity(0.7),
                    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the one variable to save the selected index item. And use the `null` if there is no selected index.

```dart
class _ListPoynts extends State<ListPoynts> {
  int? _selectedIndex; // <-- HERE

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: poynts.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            child: Container(
              width: 176,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_selectedIndex == index) { // <-- HERE
                      _selectedIndex = null;
                    } else {
                      _selectedIndex = index;
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 72,
                  width: 146,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    color: _selectedIndex == index 
                        ? constants.Colors.greenMiddle
                        : constants.Colors.greyDark.withOpacity(0.7),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as my asnwer..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Works. Tell me, how else can I make sure that the first element is always selected (the color of the first element is changed)? Now, at the beginning, no element in the list has its color changed, but I want to make sure that the color of the first element is always changed by default

Comment: @IvoBeckers Some differences exist. I'm sorry if I made you feel bad.

Comment: @MaNDOOoo true, I see you had code to deselect as well. It's okay.

Comment: @Max how about to init like `int? _selectedIndex = 0`?

Comment: Yes, I checked it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I would instead of a list of selected, just have an int. selectedIndex for example. Something like this might work:

```
class _ListPoynts extends State<ListPoynts> {

  int? _selectedIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //no need to do anything here now
    super.initState();
  }

ListView.builder(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: poynts.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              child: Container(
                width: 176,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 72,
                    width: 146,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      color: _selectedIndex == index
                          ? constants.Colors.greenMiddle
                          : constants.Colors.greyDark.withOpacity(0.7),
                    ),
```

Comment: Yes, everything works, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You just can't accept 2 answers. So I would accept your answer.

Comment: @Max to select the first at the start you could just write `int _selectedIndex = 0;` instead of `int? _selectedIndex;`

Comment: above code is good and clean. the thing missing is if you already select one container and try to deselect that means you have to check with condition and make it to empty. that only missing

Comment: And, really, everything is quite easy. Thanks again for your help.
Tell me, where can I learn more information on Flutter to improve my skill?